# Unable to find Installed SSL Certificate on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, ssl, certificates

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Is there a way to find installed SSL (Not open SSL) certificate on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: I imagine you mean Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: My bad, yes it is 14.04.

Comment: What do you mean by "installed SSL certificate"?  This could mean one of fifty different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view *all* of the certificates try the following 'for' loop:

```
for i in $(ls /etc/ssl/certs/*.pem)
do 
openssl x509 -text -noout -in $i >> my_certs
done
```

This presupposes that you cert is installed in *a standard location*, you should modify the path for a non-standard location. The loop creates the file `my_certs` that can then be opened and searched with gedit or other text editor...

**References:**

- [Viewing SSL Certificates already installed.](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/viewing-ssl-certificates-already-installed-441949/)

Answer (score 0):

This link may be help you.[http://ubuntu4u.info/](http://ubuntu4u.info/how-to-install-ubuntu-server-with-apache2-ssl-certificate/)
How to install Ubuntu Server with Apache2 SSL Certificate
Install Apache2

Required for SSL certificates to be used:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Enable SSL Module

‘default-ssl’ can be replaced by the real site name you set up in /etc/apache2/sites-available/

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

Once the site listed in the command above is enabled with that command, the site will appear in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled.
Apply SSL Module to Site

```
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```